# EXC_BAD_ACCESS error in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, exc-bad-access

I'm trying to write a simple `iOS` program that will notify when headphones are plugged/unplugged. I'm very new to `Objective-C` and `iOS`, and a lot of this code was written by somebody else and I'm now trying to adapt it so I'm having issues figuring out this problem. The code is here:

**AppDelegate.m**

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

static void onHeadsetChange(void *, AudioServicesPropertyID, UInt32, const void *);

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.headsetOnHandler = self.headsetOffHandler = ^{};
    NSLog(@"%lu", AudioSessionInitialize(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL));
    NSLog(@"%lu", AudioSessionSetActive(true));
    NSLog(@"%lu", AudioSessionAddPropertyListener(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRouteChange, &onHeadsetChange, (__bridge void *)self));
    return YES;
}

static void onHeadsetChange(void *inUserData, AudioSessionPropertyID inPropertyID, UInt32 inPropertyValueSize, const void *inPropertyValue) {
    if (inPropertyID != kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRouteChange) return;
    NSLog(@"The headset changed");
    AppDelegate *const delegate = (__bridge AppDelegate *)inUserData;

    const CFDictionaryRef routeChangeDictionary = inPropertyValue;
    const CFNumberRef routeChangeReasonRef = CFDictionaryGetValue(routeChangeDictionary, CFSTR(kAudioSession_AudioRouteChangeKey_Reason));
    SInt32 routeChangeReason;
    CFNumberGetValue(routeChangeReasonRef, kCFNumberSInt32Type, &routeChangeReason);
    switch (routeChangeReason) {
        case kAudioSessionRouteChangeReason_NewDeviceAvailable:
            //NSLog([delegate description]);
            [delegate headsetOnHandler];
            break;
        case kAudioSessionRouteChangeReason_OldDeviceUnavailable:
            [delegate headsetOffHandler];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)([UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate);
    delegate.headsetOnHandler = ^{ self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];};
    delegate.headsetOffHandler = ^{ self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];};
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

I'm getting the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS error, code=1 at [delegate headsetOnHandler] and [delegate headsetOffHandler]`. If I need to include the `.h` files for this to make sense, I will, and if there's anything else I'm missing please let me know.

EDIT:
I've added in declarations that people thought should be added:

```
@property (readwrite, assign) void (^headsetOnHandler)(void);
@property (readwrite, assign) void (^headsetOffHandler)(void);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How is the `headsetOnHandler` and `headsetOffHandler` properties declared?

If it is `assign` or `retain`, that is likely the source of your problem.  Since they are blocks, it needs to be `copy` (even, in certain cases, under ARC).   If they are `atomic` and `retain`, then your getter will call, effectively, `[[block retain] autorelease]` in the getter, which would explain your crash.

A bit of a long shot.

- when you have a crash, *always post the backtrace*
- when you know the line of code the crash is on, *always post the variable declarations of any variables on that line*

Note that ARC will change this behavior a bit, automatically handling the blocks in some cases, but -- IIRC -- you would still need to `copy` them in this case.

Comment: Thanks! Changing from `assign` to `copy` fixed the problem.